# Page numbers on first page and no logo on second page in newlfm

Tags: header-footer, newlfm

I am trying to write a cover letter with a header and footer on the first page, but no header on the consecutive pages. I also am having trouble adding a page number to the first page. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
\documentclass[10pt,stdletter, times, addrfromright]{newlfm}
\usepackage{charter}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\widowpenalty=1000
\clubpenalty=1000

\unprbottom{1cm}
\newsavebox{\Luiuc}
\sbox{\Luiuc}{%
    \parbox[b]{1.75in}{%
        \vspace{0.5in}%
        \includegraphics[scale=.15]
        {RSCAS}%
    }%
}%
\makeletterhead{Uiuc}{\Lheader{\usebox{\Luiuc}}}
\makeatletter
\let\ps@othhead\ps@fancy


\makeatother

\rfoot{ \thepage}

\Cfooter{\tiny Robert Schuman Center for Advanced Studies
 \\ European University Institute, Via dei Roccettini 9, I-50014 San Domenico di Fiesole (FI) Italy}
\newlfmP{headermarginskip=20pt}
\newlfmP{sigsize=50pt}
\newlfmP{dateskipafter=-70pt}

\newlfmP{addrfromemail}
\PhrEmail{Email}

\lthUiuc
\namefrom{John D'Attoma \\
Postdoctoral Research Fellow \\
Robert Schuman Centre for Advanced Studies \\
European University Institute}

\addrfrom{
    John D'Attoma\\
    Postdoctoral Research Fellow\\
    Robert Schuman Centre for Advanced Studies
}
\emailfrom{john.dattoma@eui.eu}

\addrto{%
The New School for Social Research\\
Department of Politics\\
66 West 12th Street \\
New York, NY 10011}

\greetto{Dear Members of the Search Committee:}
\closeline{Best Regards,}
\begin{document}
\begin{newlfm}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd forego [`newlfm`](http://ctan.org/pkg/newlfm) and choose something less restrictive. Here's a replica of your document under good ol' `article`:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{charter,fancyhdr,geometry,graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}% For this example

\geometry{paper=letterpaper,
  hmargin=1in,
  vmargin=.5in,
  includefoot
}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% No header rule
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}% 1pt footer rule
\fancyfoot[C]{%
  \tiny
  \begin{tabular}{c}
    Robert Schuman Center for Advanced Studies \\
    European University Institute, Via dei Roccettini 9, I-50014 San Domenico di Fiesole (FI) Italy
  \end{tabular}}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% No paragraph indent
\setlength{\parskip}{.5\baselineskip}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics[scale=.15]{example-image} \\% Your logo here
\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}

\hfill
\begin{tabular}{l@{}}
  John D'Attoma \\
  Postdoctoral Research Fellow \\
  Robert Schuman Centre for Advanced Studies \\
  Email: john.dattoma@eui.eu
\end{tabular}

\bigskip\bigskip

\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l}
  The New School for Social Research\\
  Department of Politics\\
  66 West 12th Street \\
  New York, NY 10011
\end{tabular}
\hfill
\today

\bigskip

Dear Members of the Search Committee:

\bigskip

\lipsum[1-7]

\bigskip

\hfill
\begin{tabular}{l@{}}
  Best Regards, \\[50pt]
  John D'Attoma \\
  Postdoctoral Research Fellow \\
  Robert Schuman Centre for Advanced Studies \\
  European University Institute
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Output before switching away from your class:

[image]

Output using the above code:

[image]